# AnyDesk is not working

Tags: 17.10, ambiance

AnyDesk is not working and this is hampering my work. In log it's giving the following error message:

> /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/apps/mate-panel.rc:30: error: invalid string constant "murrine-scrollbar", expected valid string constant

Answer (score 1):

This error can be solved by changing line 30 (as indicated by the string *mate-panel.rc**:30*** in your question) in `/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/apps/mate-panel.rc` as shown below. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo -i  
cd /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/apps  
cp mate-panel.rc mate-panel.rc.bak # backup mate-panel.rc file before editing it  
nano mate-panel.rc
```

Now mate-panel will be open for editing in nano text editor. Scroll down with the <kbd>↓</kbd> key and change the following line which is line 30, the last line in my mate-panel.rc file:

```
class "GtkScrollbar"              style "murrine-scrollbar"
```

by replacing the string "murrine-scrollbar" with "scrollbar" so that it looks like this:

```
class "GtkScrollbar"              style "scrollbar"
```

Press the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and after that press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the changes in mate-panel.rc. Press the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit nano.

Logout in the terminal from root back to normal user.

```
exit
```

Now you will be able to use  without getting an error message that says: `/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/apps/mate-panel.rc:30: error: invalid string constant "murrine-scrollbar", expected valid string constant`

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple solution to this problem, this occurred due to ubuntu switching to Wayland as their default display driver.

To resolve this issue you simply have to logout from user and switch to xorg instead of Wayland from settings available at user login window.